# Add todays date to mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below insert to add data to a mysql table. I have created a date field in the db called 'Date'. How can I add todays date to the insert?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO queries SET Name='$Name', Email='$Email', Telephone='$Telephone', Country='$Country', Referrer='$Referrer', Website='$Website'";
```

Comment: `NOW()` in your query.

Comment: another solution: you could modify the date row and let it auto-populate with the current date, by using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `DEFAULT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: @cweinberger I think CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will not work because type is date not time.

Comment: Use cur_date() to add today's date. Check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL now() function

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO queries SET Name='$Name', Email='$Email', Telephone='$Telephone', Country='$Country', Referrer='$Referrer', Website='$Website', date=NOW()";
```

Comment: I have tried this and the entry in the db just shows as 0000-00-00

Comment: I have checked it. It should work. please make sure that you haven't add single quotes for now() function(ex: 'now()').
The reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 0):

by php

```
$time = time();
$sql = "INSERT INTO queries SET Name='$Name', Email='$Email', Telephone='$Telephone', Country='$Country', Referrer='$Referrer', Website='$Website', `Date` = $time";
```

i added time by unix , because that's will be easy to make operation in at

Answer (score 0):

you could use `CURDATE()`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO queries SET Name='$Name', Email='$Email', Telephone='$Telephone', Country='$Country', Referrer='$Referrer', Website='$Website', `Date` = CURDATE()";
```